# JustEat delivery checker script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am starting to learn Python and just wondering if someone could help me with my first script.

As you can see from the code below, the script will open a firefox service and grab details from a Just-Eat page and if they are delivering then return up or down.

If they are down then it should open a web WhatsApp page and send a message to a set group.

What I am trying to do now and this is where I'm getting stuck, if the site reports down I want to run the check again and if it is down saying another 4 times then return that the site is down. This could stop me from getting false returns at times.

Also, I know this code could be made faster and stronger but it is my first time coding in Python :-) positive and constructive comments are welcomed.
Thanks guys <3

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
import pywhatkit
from datetime import datetime
import keyboard

print("Delivery checker v1.0")

def executeSomething():
    ser = Service(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\drivers\geckodriver.exe")
    my_opt = Options()
    my_opt.headless = True

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=my_opt, service=ser)
    driver.get("https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-mcdonaldsstevenstonhawkhillretailpark-stevenston/menu")
    driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]").click()

    status = driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/main/header/section/div[1]/p/span")
    
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")


    if status.text == "Delivering now":
        print("[" + dt_string + "] - up")
    else:        
        print("[" + dt_string + "] - down [" + str(counter) + "]")
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly("HpYQbjTU5fz728BGjiS45K", "MCDONALDS ISNT SHOWING UP ON JUST EAT!!!!")
            keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w')
    driver.close()    
    time.sleep(1)
    
while True:
    executeSomething()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

```
down_count = 0
down_max = 4
while True:
    if is_web_down():
        down_count += 1
    else:
        down_count = 0

    if down_count >= down_max:
        send_message()

    time.sleep(1)
```

You just need to refactor executeSomething() to 2 functions: is_web_down() and send_message()

Comment: Thank you so much, I take it then in my "is_web_down" function I will just be returning true or false now?

Comment: @iamlundy Yup it should return True if it's down and False if up